# How to open a file in solution directory in Visual Studio c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I would like to open a file in the solution directory so that whenever i move the whole project file, It'll work.

I'm currently using code ! as shown below and when i tried to use code 2, it fails.
How do i do this?

**Code 1:**

```
IplImage *src=cvLoadImage("C:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Project1\\ABC.jpg"); //A function that load image
```

**Code 2:**

```
`IplImage *src=cvLoadImage("$(SolutionDir)/ABC.jpg"); //A function that load image
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
"..\\example.txt"
```

that will find the file on top project directory.

Also doesn't `cvLoadImage` takes 2 argument! I assuming you are using OpenCV

Comment: BTW, cvLoadImage is indeed a openCV function.
It works with one argument as well, with its default RGB as second argument.